# PHP - Meaning of T_STRING

Tags: string, php

Can someone explain what the T_STRING error is in php?

Its is found in many php error messages, but what exactly is a T_STRING?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php

Comment: Can you post some code to where it has occurred?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`T_STRING` referes to a literal string object inside the scripts source code. Just like language constructs (print, if, ...) they have a special meaning on a syntactical level.

So an error mentioning something like an 'unexpected T_STRING' usually points towards a syntax error where the compiler found a string where it expected something else, typically a closing bracket or something else.

Answer (score 2):

T_STRING is exactly what you might expect it to be, a String token.... often it's the name of a function (you might see it if you miss a semi-colon on one line, and the next line of code comprises a function call) or a variable (where you've forgotten the $ variable indicator)